# Removing consecutive duplicates in a postgresql database where data is in json column

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

So I have a postgresql table called `state_data` where there are two columns: `datetime` and `state`. The `state` column is of jsonb type and specifies various state data for a given datetime.  Here is an example of the table:

```
datetime            | state
================================================
2018-10-31 08:00:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:01:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:02:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:03:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":2}
2018-10-31 08:04:00 | {"temp":74.8,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:05:00 | {"temp":74.8,"location":2}
2018-10-31 08:06:00 | {"temp":74.7,"location":1}
```

Over time this table will get very big - particularly I increase sampling frequency - and I really only want to store data where consecutive rows have different temperatures. So the table above would reduce to,

```
datetime            | state
================================================
2018-10-31 08:00:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:04:00 | {"temp":74.8,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:06:00 | {"temp":74.7,"location":1}
```

I know how to do this if the temperature data were in its own column, but is there a straightforward way to handle this operation and delete all consecutive duplicates based on an item within a json column?

What if I wanted to delete duplicates for both json items? For example,

```
datetime            | state
================================================
2018-10-31 08:00:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:03:00 | {"temp":75.0,"location":2}
2018-10-31 08:04:00 | {"temp":74.8,"location":1}
2018-10-31 08:05:00 | {"temp":74.8,"location":2}
2018-10-31 08:06:00 | {"temp":74.7,"location":1}
```

Comment: I figured out I can use AND statement in your last line to solve the condition based on intersection of two subconditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the window function `lag():`

```
select datetime, state
from (
    select datetime, state, lag(state) over (order by datetime) as prev
    from state_data
    ) s
where state->>'temp' is distinct from prev->>'temp'
```

If the table has a primary key you should use it in the delete command. In the lack of a primary key you can cast `state` to jsonb:

```
delete from state_data
where (datetime, state::jsonb) not in (
    select datetime, state::jsonb
    from (
        select datetime, state, lag(state) over (order by datetime) as prev
        from state_data
        ) s
    where state->>'temp' is distinct from prev->>'temp'
)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a dumb questions, but what does the `s` do in the penultimate line?

Comment: `s` is an alias - subquery in FROM must have an alias. I've updated the answer with the delete command.

Comment: What if I wanted to modify such that it deletes duplicate records of temp AND location (see modified question)?

Comment: You can use `and` or compare `state::jsonb` to `prev::jsonb`. The issue is that you cannot compare json columns (have to cast to jsonb)

Comment: Yes, state is in jsonb. I edited original post to reflect same. Thanks.